# Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation : "Value cannot be null"

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am trying to link associate sites to one of hubsite but i end with strange error saying Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation : "Value cannot be null".

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite -Credentials (Get-Credential)
    $Sites = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\username\Documents\Book1.csv"
    $myHubsite = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite"
    foreach ($site in $Sites) {
      error->  Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation -Site $site.SiteUrl -HubSite $myHubsite
    }
```

I tried with single site still same error

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite -Credentials (Get-Credential)
    Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation -Site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite1 -HubSite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite
```

Error message:

```
Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
At line:4 char:5
+     Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation -Site $site.SiteUrl -HubSite $myHubsite
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentNullException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Admin.AddHubSiteAssociation
```

I can connect to to my hub and i get variables too

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my end and the cmdlet `Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation` works fine. It seems the issue shall be the import-csv does not generate the sites properly. Have a check on the variable `$sites`, make sure the parameter `$site` has a proper URL to the site.

Comment: However, i tried this method instead of bulk Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation -Site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite1 -HubSite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite but i see the same error. Could be some dependencies missing ?

Comment: I am getting the proper url in $site from variable $sites

Comment: @striker92 That is strange. I think you have set up the pnp connection. Would you like to test with other sites? Is the testSite a hub site?

Comment: i have edited the main question,  my complete script looks like that. Yes my test site is a hubsite

Comment: Do i have to edit any settings on hubsite or permissions ?

Comment: It was a permission issue, now i can link associate sites to hubsite. Thank you !

Comment: @striker92, you will need to connect to the site not the hub site. As it is a setting for that site, not for the hub site.

Comment: i had tried that way either, did not work because i was not an admin to the site. It was a permission issue, it needs to be admin in first place to link associate sites to the hubsite. Thank you for your suggestions.